# How to execute grep in tcl for getting XYZ-123 type pattern

Tags: scripting, grep, tcl

How can I execute this grep command in TCL?

`grep '[A-Z][A-Z][A-Z]\-[0-9][0-9][0-9]' file1 > file2`

Answer (score 1):

**tcl** uses curly-braces as quotes rather than single-quote marks.  This would work:

```
grep {[A-Z][A-Z][A-Z]-[0-9][0-9][0-9]} file1 > file2
```

but keep in mind that if there are no matches, there will *still* be an error reported, e.g.,

```
child process exited abnormally
    while executing
"exec grep {[A-Z][A-Z][A-Z]-[0-9][0-9][0-9]} file1 > file2"
    (file "./foo" line 4)
```

For *that*, the [Tcl documentation](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/exec.htm) points out that you should wrap your command in a `catch` block, e.g.,

```
set status 0
if {[catch {exec grep {[A-Z][A-Z][A-Z]-[0-9][0-9][0-9]} file1 > file2} results options]} {
    set details [dict get $options -errorcode]
    if {[lindex $details 0] eq "CHILDSTATUS"} {
        set status [lindex $details 2]
    } else {
        puts "unexpected error $options $results"
        set status 99
    }
}
```

Further reading:

- [tcl - Understanding the usage of braces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2193641/understanding-the-usage-of-braces)
  One of the answers says that curly braces are analogous to the shell's single-quotes and double-quotes act like the shell's double-quotes, but does not clarify that the latter act *within* **tcl** and using double-quotes will produce an `invalid command name "A-Z"` error.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried just using `exec`?

I.e.:

```
exec grep "[A-Z][A-Z][A-Z]\-[0-9][0-9][0-9]" file1 > file2
```